# about xmlrpcpp/XmlRpcException.h

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I catkin_make the robot_localization package it says:

```
fatal error: xmlrpcpp/XmlRpcException.h: No such file or directory
 #include <xmlrpcpp/XmlRpcException.h>
```

how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258860/about-xmlrpcpp/xmlrpcexception.h/) by [lowme](https://answers.ros.org/users/29974/lowme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-04-10**:
Are you trying to compile the robot_localization package from source code? If so, have you tried to run rosdep before catkin_make?

**Comment by [lowme](https://answers.ros.org/users/29974/lowme/) on 2017-04-10**:
I have done as you said,but it don't work

**Comment by [lowme](https://answers.ros.org/users/29974/lowme/) on 2017-04-10**:
I replaced  #include <xmlrpcpp/XmlRpcException.h> as #include <XmlRpcException.h> and #include <string.h> it works thank you.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-04-11**:
Which branch are you using?

**Comment by [lowme](https://answers.ros.org/users/29974/lowme/) on 2017-04-11**:
I want to fuse GPS IMU and DMI.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-04-11**:
What branch of the GitHub repository are you using?

**Comment by [zobocop](https://answers.ros.org/users/30009/zobocop/) on 2017-04-13**:
I'm having the same issue. Just cloned the latest version of kinetic-devel. There is no directory named xmlrcpp in the include/robot_localization directory, is it meant to be installed by the user?

**Comment by [zobocop](https://answers.ros.org/users/30009/zobocop/) on 2017-04-13**:
Fixed by running rosdep install [package] on any packages that threw an error during catkin_make. For robot_localization this triggered an apt-get installation. I had originally used git clone as I was updating an old version of robot_localization.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2017-10-20**:
Same issue. Cloned latest kinetic-devel branch, ran rosdep update, confirmed ros-indigo-xmlrpcpp is installed, but same error when compiling. Is this an issue because I'm running Indigo?

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2017-10-20**:
I see now that the headers were pushed into a directory in [ros_comm](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/a8c5f9e95e6823417b67ee0da2fa0a91acd97ef5) starting with 1.12.7 and Indigo release version is 1.11.21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I replaced  #include <xmlrpcpp/XmlRpcException.h> as #include <XmlRpcException.h> and #include <string.h> it works thank you.

---

Originally posted by [lowme](https://answers.ros.org/users/29974/lowme/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0